# iOS device login function

Tags: html, ios

Is there any way for IOS devices to enter my website after i check their personal UDID beforehand?

And for the devices that their UDID are not registered in my website’s Database to not access my website?

Comment: No, your website cannot access the device identifier.

Comment: If i make it access by user agreement can i do it ?

Comment: No, you can't. Web sites don't have access to the device identifier for very good privacy reasons. You can't ask the user to provide it. Even if you could it wouldn't be a good security mechanism

Comment: I seen website with this functionality

Comment: You can ask the user to install a device management profile that will return the device identifier but you can’t correlate this device identifier with an access to your website in Safari. You can get an advertising identifier in Safari but the user can block or change this at any time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I asking for. So can i do it please

Comment: Which? Install an MDM profile or read the advertising Id?

Comment: Both of them please